# Suggest a best suitable design patten

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a problem statement where I need to design classes in such a way that there behavior is decided at runtime.

The class heirarchy is as follows;

```
                       Base
          ______________|________________
         |           |        |         |      
       Drvd-A     DrvdB     DrvdC   Drvd-Generic
```

An instance of type "Drvd-Generic" should inherit in principle the behavior of any of the classes "Drvd-A", "Drvd-B" or "Drvd-C" at runtime.

The behavior of instance "Drvd-Generic"will be decided at runtime and can be changed at runtime too.
For instance; 
   - created instance Drvd-Generic;
   - for a specific time and under certain conditions Drvd-Generic should inherit the behavior of Drvd-A;
   - after trigering some changes Drvd-Generic should inherit the behavior of Drvd-B;

This will happen at runtime under occurence of certain conditions and instance of Drvd-Generic will be same for the life time of program.

Suggest a best fit design pattern to suit the case.

Comment: Try the [Dartboard](http://www.codingthewheel.com/image.axd?picture=design_patterns_dartboard.jpg). Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

`Drvd-Generic` could implement the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern, and use internal instances of `DrvdA` / `DrvdB` etc to do its work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a **strategy pattern** w/ composition would work, where you have a member of type `Behavior`. (pseudocode follows)

```
class Behavior
{
   virtual execute() = 0;
}
class BehaviorA
{
   virtual execute();
}
//and others

class Base
{
   Behavior* behavior;
}
class Drvd-A : Base
{
   //set behavior to BehaviorA
}
//and others
class Drvd-Generic
{
   //set & change behavior at runtime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)?

```
interface Base
{
//This is the interface which specifies the members
}
class Drvd-Generic : Base
{
//This implements the base class
}
class DrvdA : Base
{
//This class has a member of type Drvd-Generic
//The constructor accespts the Drvd-Generic object
//This can define DrvdA specific functions to further work on it.
//Basically this is the decorator class.
//As are DrvdB and DrvdC
}
class DrvdB : Base
{
}
class DrvdC : Base
{
}
```

Hope this helps you.